# SPDY web server benchmarking tools

Tags: http, tcp, webserver, benchmarking, spdy

I've created a web server which uses SPDY. I would like to benchmark my web server under SPDY and compare the results to the standard TCP/HTTP protocols. Are there any tools which I could use to simulate over a 1000 requests to my web server under SPDY?

Also what tool could I use to simulate over a 1000 UDP messages being sent to an application (just to compare the latency with UDP to that of SPDY)?

Comment: @HYS backticks are for `inline code`, not for highlighting random terms. That edit should not have been approved.

Comment: [link](http://www.neotys.com/product/technologies-spdy-load-testing.html) seems to offer loadtesting of SPDY servers. I have never used it so I can't comment on how good it is.

Answer (score 0):

Because SPDY offers benefits with multi-resource loading, I would recommend a client-side testing tool like PhantomJS and calculating `document.onload` times to fully measure downloaded resources and JavaScript executions.  ApacheBench would only measure server response times (excluding JS and associated files, and I'm not sure if it renegotiates TLS handshakes upon every connection.

Here's a test that benchmarks 350 requests: http://www.httpvshttps.com/